# Why is sass --update not going fast when run from php exec?

Tags: php, sass

I'm using sass in a php-based application and am trying to use the --update option so that the sass code is not recompiled every time the browser requests the corresponding css file. When I run the sass command on the command-line, it works as expected (longer compile time after a sass file has been changed, short compile time if not). When I run it from php using exec, it seems to take long enough that it must be recompiling every time. Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Use [`microtime()`](http://php.net/microtime#example-670) to accurately record the length of time it takes. This way you can be sure it isn't something else in the script causing the issue.

Comment: Did that. Also ran the script from the command-line using the time command (i.e. time php script.php) and it seemed to work faster. Perhaps something related to the user/permissions that the webserver is running under?

Comment: That could be a cause. If the web server does not have permission to write to the file then it will always think it is changed as it cannot update it. Try setting it to 777 just for testing - to eliminate this as a cause.

Comment: also ran filemtime() on the input(sass) file and the output(css) file prior to running the exec command. php accurately retrieved the last modified time of both files. Also ran filemtime() on the output file after the exec and modified time did not change, which would indicate that it was not updated.

Comment: I don't have SASS or Ruby setup on this machine so I cannot test and I usually use LESS anyway so I am gonna have to bow out of this one.

Comment: could it be that you are using more than one machine (e.g., an nfs server) and that their times are not in sync (ntpd is not running)?

Comment: Nope, I'm running this all on one machine. the filemtime function confirms that the timestamps are being read correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with the default caching location when running as the web server. Specifying a cache directory using the --cache-location option seemed to fix the problem and make it run much faster.